# Missing rate limiting headers in Azure API responses

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, throttling

My app is being throttled by Azure Management API and it'd be much easier to investigate which requests are causing troubles if I have access to rate limiting headers. I thought they're returned by default but they're not, at least not for me. I've followed steps listed in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling#retrieving-the-header-values) but none of rate limiting headers is returned. I even upgraded Azure CLI to the latest version but it didn't help either.

So the question is whether I need to enable something in Azure portal to retrieve this kind of information or maybe it's something else. Anyway, I'd be very thankful for any help as I feel a bit confused.

Here's an example response:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourcegroups?api-version=2021-04-01

HTTP/2 200 
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
expires: -1
x-ms-request-id: d093ff31-9b06-41dd-9c3a-6e7b7275e02
x-ms-correlation-request-id: d093ff31-9b06-41dd-9c3a-6e7b7275e023
x-ms-routing-request-id: EASTUS2:20211024T140342Z:d093ff31-9b06-41dd-9c3a-6e7b7275e023
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
date: Sun, 24 Oct 2021 14:03:42 GMT
content-length: 289

<JSON_DATA>
```

Comment: Which specific headers are you expecting but not receiving? There are some headers which will be returned only after the limit is exceeded. What is the rate limit policy you have configured in APIM ?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran if I understand correctly APIM is about user-defined API but in my issue I refer to Azure Management API that is delivered by Azure to interact with VMs, volumes, network interfaces etc. And in that case I can't configure any rate limit policies because they're defined by Azure as listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling#subscription-and-tenant-limits)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I've added an example response in the post. As you can see I doesn't contain any rate limiting headers but based on the article I sent it should.

Comment: In the article, it mentions to use the Debug argument for Powershell, and the verbose param for Azure CLI to get those rate-limit headers. You could you try that, for instance try to use this Powershell script https://github.com/microsoft/csa-misc-utils/blob/master/psh-GetArmLimitsViaAPI/GetArmLimits.ps1

Comment: I am not sure, but the documentation not guarantees these headers in normal load, only when the limits are 'nearing' to be exceeded these headers may be returned. These limits are also different for different Az resources, and are 'per user' in most cases. Are you sure you got many 429 error codes,and even during that response headers were missing? None of the documents talk about enabling any flag or settings in the Az portal to receive these limit headers. So, you could raise a Microsoft support ticket I guess.